# Why does Matlab's solve function take less time after being run once?

Tags: matlab, performance, runtime, solver

I have some Matlab code that calls the solve function on some symbolic constraints.  The first time it runs, solve takes ~6 seconds.  After the first time, solve takes ~0.3 seconds.  If I change the input variables, solve takes ~6 seconds again.

Is this because, on the executions after the first, Matlab remembers it had the answer before and simply reuses it? Or is something else happening?

Below is some code that will demonstrate this behaviour.

```
clear; clc

d1 = 25;
d2 = 15;
d3 = 7.5;
d4 = 4.5;

x1 = -0.1521;
y1 = 0.2673;
z1 = 2.3;

x21 = -0.3473;
y21 = 0.3298;

x3 = -0.434;
y3 = 0.2502;
z3 = 2.3;

g = [x1-x3,y1-y3,z1-z3];


syms  X1 Y1 Z1  X2 Y2 Z2  X3 Y3 Z3  X4 Y4 Z4 ...
    x22 y22 z22 t2_2d t1_2d ...
    t1 t2 t3 t4 ...
    real
assumeAlso([Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4 t1 t2 t3],'positive')


constraints = [
        x22 == (t2_2d * (-1/g(1)) ) + x21
        x22 == (t1_2d * g(1)) + x1

        y22 == (t2_2d * (-1/g(2)) ) + y21
        y22 == (t1_2d * g(2)) + y1

        z22 == z1


        X1 == t1*x1
        Y1 == t1*y1
        Z1 == t1*z1

        X2 == t2*x22
        Y2 == t2*y22
        Z2 == t2*z22

        X3 == t3*x3
        Y3 == t3*y3
        Z3 == t3*z3


        (X1-X3)^2 + (Y1-Y3)^2 + (Z1-Z3)^2 == (d1+d2)^2
        (X1-X2)^2 + (Y1-Y2)^2 + (Z1-Z2)^2 == d1^2
        (X2-X3)^2 + (Y2-Y3)^2 + (Z2-Z3)^2 == d2^2


        sum([X4 Y4 Z4] .* cross([X1 Y1 Z1],[X3 Y3 Z3])) == 0
        (X1-X4)^2 + (Y1-Y4)^2 + (Z1-Z4)^2 == (d1+d2+d3)^2 + d4^2
        (X3-X4)^2 + (Y3-Y4)^2 + (Z3-Z4)^2 == d3^2 + d4^2
];

tic
solved = solve(constraints);
toc

tic
solved = solve(constraints);
toc

tic
solved = solve(constraints);
toc

tic
solved = solve(constraints);
toc
```

The motivation behind this question is that I'd like to be running the solver as quickly as possible with the same constraints on changing inputs. I hope an answer will help me find a way to have a ~0.3 second runtime each time instead of a ~6 second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is because the code will be cached when executed for the first time, so subsequent runs will be faster. By changing the parameters, you have to run the code once to so that the new definitions are cached.

MATLAB can cache script handles by using a temporary directory. For instance, do `clean all`, then run `[M,X,C] = inmem('-completenames')` before and after running your script. You'll notice that the following classes were cached:

```
{'matlab.internal.editor.eval.TempFolder'                           }
{'matlab.internal.editor.eval.TmpFilePath'                          }
{'matlab.internal.editor.EODataStore'                               }
```

But regarding the performance, I looked into it and about 99% of the 3 second runtime is spent evaluating the symbolic expressions when it is passed into solve(), so it is expected that the runtime will be much lower for subsequent runs, since your symbolic expressions are unchanged. Now, by changing the parameters, you'll have to wait the 3 seconds again for it to be reevaluated. If you want to see exactly what is happening, you can profile your solve() call:

```
profile on
solved = solve(constraints);
profile viewer
```

Then you can see what is happening inside mupadengine.evalin, which is the  one responsible for the symbolic expression evaluation.

Comment: What do you mean "code will be cached"? If you run a script and not a file or a function, how can it be cached?

Comment: I would upvote +0.5 if it was available... :)  I know about the `clear all` - `inmem`, but it caches the function, not the "code", or a variable. I can get that `solve` get cached, and `profiler` can be a right way to investigate here. But changing inputs should not change the cache of the function...

Comment: You're right, I should have edited the first paragraph where I said that. But the main point is that the symbolic evaluation will be the long portion of the computation. Hope I was of some help at least :)

Comment: You do have some direction, but I don't think it can be considered as an answer.